# How to use echo command to output escape sequence for color

Tags: bash

```
domain="www.google.com"
echo -e "\e[1;34m"$domain"\e[0m"
```

I expected this to output `www.google.com` in green letters.

Instead I got

`-e \e[1;34mwww.google.com\e[0m`

Comment: Is your shell really bash? I suspect it's not. If this is a script, put `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, the shebang is already at the top.

Comment: How are you running it? `./script.sh` or `sh script.sh`? Don't do the latter.

Comment: the latter~!!!!!

Comment: Its working fine on my Ubuntu, Kali, Backtract and Parrot also. Could you tell me which version of Linux you are working with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending the environment or shell used can have an effect, one thing you could probably do is to use `ANSI-C` quoting:

```
echo $'\e[1;34m'${domain}$'\e[0m'
```

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
>   string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
>   ANSI C standard.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Comment: @user299709: One other alternative is to use the escape code `\033` instead of `\e` (eg. `echo -e '\033[1;34m'"${domain}"'\033[0m'`)... some shells don't use `\e` and in such a case you'll generally have to use an alternative means of escaping characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you run a script with `sh script.sh`, you're explicitly using `sh` as the shell rather than the one in the shebang line. That's bad news if `sh` isn't a link to `bash`. A plain `sh` shell may not support `echo -e`.

Type `./script.sh` to use the interpreter in the shebang line.

Comment: while this is a valid answer, I chose ILI's answer as it directly allowed me to display colors without having to change the way I was running the script.

Comment: @user299709 Don't run a script with `sh` if it uses `bash`-specific features.

Comment: You *should* change the way you're running the script, though.